# why org.jasypt.exceptions.EncryptionOperationNotPossibleException

Tags: java, servlets, encryption, jasypt

Here are my Encryptor class methods:

```
    public String encrypt(String str){ 
        if(str == null || str.equals("")){
            str = "";
        }
        else{
            StandardPBEStringEncryptor encryptor = new StandardPBEStringEncryptor();
            encryptor.setPassword(mpCryptoPassword);
            str = encryptor.encrypt(str);
        } 
    return str;
    }
    public String decrypt(String str){
        if(str == null || str.equals("")){
            str = "";
        }
        else{
            StandardPBEStringEncryptor decryptor = new StandardPBEStringEncryptor();
            decryptor.setPassword(mpCryptoPassword);
            str = decryptor.decrypt(str);
        }
    return str;
    }
```

I am trying to encrypt as following:

```
String encryptedToken   = "";
//preparing token email + time
Date now            = new Date();               
String prepareToken = "email="+email+"&tokenTime="+now.getTime();

//encrypt url value
Encryptor enc       = new Encryptor();
encryptedToken      = enc.encrypt(prepareToken);
```

and I am decrypting like:

```
Encryptor enc           = new Encryptor();
String decryptedToken   = enc.decrypt(encryptedToken);
```

Then its throwing error:

> org.jasypt.exceptions.EncryptionOperationNotPossibleException
>           at org.jasypt.encryption.pbe.StandardPBEByteEncryptor.decrypt(StandardPBEByteEncryptor.java:1055)
>           at org.jasypt.encryption.pbe.StandardPBEStringEncryptor.decrypt(StandardPBEStringEncryptor.java:725)
>           at com.cryptography.Encryptor.decrypt(Encryptor.java:57)
>           at com.users.forgot.ResetPassword.doGet(ResetPassword.java:72)
>           at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
>           at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>           at filters.charsetFilter.filter.CharsetFilter.doFilter(CharsetFilter.java:61)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:128)
>           at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
>           at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:286)
>           at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:845)
>           at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:583)
>           at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:447)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)

**Update**
I noticed its working sometime but not working when there is + sign in the encrypted string as its getting + as space

Answer (score 0):

The problem that I found is plus + sign in encrypted string. When I was decrypting it was getting + as white space from URL.

```
encryptedToken = encryptedToken.replaceAll(" ","+");
```

solve this problem